# Unity stuttering phenomenon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a factory game in Unity, and a sudden stutter occurred, so I tried to figure out what was the problem through a profiler.

[image: 프로파일러 스크린샷]
As a result, I found out that the delay occurs in a function called UpdateSlopSliding, and also that the delay occurs when processing garbage.

So I looked at the code, but I think there is no problem with this code. If you know the cause of this delay in the editor, please advise.
[image]

Comment: does it change if you do castorigin = transform.position - (Vector3.up*spherecastverticaloffset)+controller.center ?

Comment: Not sure which line here even allocates memory, maybe SphereCast? Try replacing lines with dummy values until you find which one is doing the allocation. And when it comes to GC, it's sometimes not enough to just fix one function, you gotta mind how you allocate memory across the program, especially in code which runs frequently. The profiler can help you find those places. Techniques like pooling and object reuse can help you solve them.

Comment: Also don't post pictures of code. Just paste in the code.